# How i can use the same audio jack for input line and headphone output

Tags: switches, audio, protection, headphones, line

I have an audio circuit that can record and play audio (saw schematic). I have a DAC and a class D amplifier for playing audio through headphone but i wanted to try to use the same audio jack for record audio from smartphone or PC.

Just, i don't know really I can use the same audio jack for output (when playing record) and input (when i want to record) ...

Can I connect headphone output to the class D amplifier and the same line on the ADC input but I need to protect the class D amplifier during recording ? If i put some diode this is ok ?

Or maybe, i can create a switch with some resistor for protecting the amplifier ?

Do you have some ideas where i can start looking ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnlzuP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, just make sure that the input to your ADC (or whatever) is compatible with the impedance of the amplifier.

If not you could use a relay or other switch, and switch the audio lines of the connector from your amp to your ADC.

Like this circuit, but one could be your ADC for input and the other part of the switch for your amp.

[image]
Source: [Kbarret](https://www.kbarrett.com/blog/2009/10/11/audio-output-selector.html)

Another way is to probably use a 4 line audio jack and a splitter

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. About the splitter, why i need a 4 line audio ? Can i use a resistive splitter (not efficient maybe ...) with one input and two output (one for the amplifier and one for the ADC) ?

Comment: You could use one or the other, you don't need both. Thats why I used the term 'another way'

Comment: Be sure to upvote and mark the best answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless you disable the 0 output impedance of the speaker driver , you wont be able to use the high impedance input of the ADC.  Windows has certain drivers that permit recording "what you hear" that are available for some motherboards.  There are also other audio drivers that allow reconfiguring audio ports as inputs or outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The diodes as you drew them will not work.

You need some kind of switch. When you plug a jack on your PC, usually you can configure what it will do (input, output...), this feature uses electronic switches inside the audio chipset which route the signal to the proper destination.

In your case, yes you can use a relay as shown by laptop2d, but it would be simpler and cheaper to have one output jack and one input jack.